# Set css in svg element

Tags: css, html, svg

I have a svg image element. I have to set margin for image.

```
<svg id="chart" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" viewBox="0 0 960 500">

    <image class="leaf" x="240.9471668231492" y="362.4164063706163" width="80" height="80" href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/ML_maple_leaf.png"></image>
<svg>
```

My css is:-

```
.leaf
{
   margin-top:80px;
}
```

Why my css is not working. Is there any othere way to set css in svg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the SVG standard doesn't specify anything like margin, which is why it's handled inconsistently. Just set the correct x and y of your image and the correct size of your svg

Comment: I have already seen this answer in SO. I thought if there is any new options are available. Are you sure there is no other option.

Comment: Yes, i'm sure. Svg use coordinates to place your elements as you want. margin and padding are useless in this case. that's why they decided not to implement that.